# Update 1 column with the unique value of that column from multiple subsets of rows sharing the same value for another column

Tags: sqlite

I issue the following UPDATE

```
UPDATE mytable SET col1=(SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM mytable WHERE col2=2) WHERE col2=2;
```

mytable has 100 groups of rows. Each group has the same value for col2, and should have the same for col1 but currently col1 is NULL in some rows.

So I would simply like to combine the above query with

```
SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM mytable
```

and have the UPDATE apply for each value of col2

Is it possible as a sqlite query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is what you want:

```
update mytable 
set col1 = (select max(m.col1) from mytable m where m.col2 = mytable.col2)
where col1 is null
```

This will update all the groups.
If you want to update only the group for `col2 = 2` change the `WHERE` clause:

```
where col2 = 2 and col1 is null
```